# django media url correct but not showing the picture

Tags: python, django

so i make a test Django project to fix the problem i have in my website is that the image wont display but when i see the url in the console its the correct MEDIA_URL that i set(the picture at the bottom) i know maybe the problem is in my urlpatterns but i can't seems to find what it is here is my code.

urls.py

```
    from django.urls import path
    from . import views
    from django.conf import settings
    from django.conf.urls.static import static

    urlpatterns = [
        path("",views.index,name="index"),
        path('callback/', views.callback, name='callback')
    ] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL,document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

and sorry here is my model i edit

```
    class transaksi_user(models.Model):
        line_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
        img_transaksi = models.ImageField(upload_to='image_transaksi')
        read_by_admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)

        def __str__(self):
            return self.line_name
```

views.py

```
    def index(request):
        user1 = transaksi_user.objects.all()
        return render(request,"messanger.html",{"user":user1})
```

template

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        {% for users in user%}
        <h1>{{users.line_name}}</h1>
        <img src="{{users.img_transaksi.url}}">
        {% endfor %}
    </body>
    </html>
```

settings.py

```
    STATIC_URL = '/static/'
    STATICFILES_DIRS = [
        os.path.join(BASE_DIR,"staticfiles")
    ]
    STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,"assets")
    MEDIA_URL ='/media/'
    MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'media')
```

when i add the new image in django admin page it work and it locate the media file and save it there but when i try to view the image by click the url in django admin it show me error like this

[image: django admin new image]

[image: error image]

and in my console its the correct media url too

[image: console image]

Comment: plz share your template where you are showing image

Comment: i update my code please check it :)

Answer (score 0):

In Django, you cannot click on the URL in the admin portal to view the files. These URLs are truncated and do not represent the exact file location in the project folder. So its only /media/image_transaksi...  rather than C:/Project folder/Static/media/image_transaksi (or similar).

However, you can use to render these files in the templates using something like this:

```
{{ image_transaksi.url }}
```

Django ensures that this will find the whole path and the image will be rendered as intended.

Comment: but when i render it to my template it shown the correct media url in console but it return 400 error code

Comment: yes, the admin "url" is not complete and is a truncated version. So clicking there will not render anything.

Comment: try to see my template code as you can see i done that  in my template that is message.html but it still not showing the image at all and i check through the console it still return the 400 error code but the url is correct one that i set and after that i check my other project that use MEDIA_URL too and it work but can't seem to understand why my main project wont work.

Comment: My felling was right there was something going on in my urlspattern i just fix it dude..thanks for taking time to answer this question :)